# How do I update custom field post meta in frontend post template?

Tags: custom-field, templates, post-meta, front-end

I would like to create a custom field with meta key `isFlagged` when user click on the `flag` link in the post template.

I know this can be easily done in the post edit page in the backend Dashboard, but I want to get this done in the frontend post page.

I'm planning to use

```
<?php
    if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        // display the one-click flagging link
    }
?>
```

in `single.php` to check the condition only certain roles can perform the one-click flagging.

I noted that `update_post_meta()` can be used to get this done.

But how do I create a link that will trigger this function in the Wordpress template file?  eg. single.php

Comment: Do you mean clicking a link will fire post meta update?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve.